# Qt QAxWidget - WebBrowser setting slots/signals manually

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qt5, slot

I've studied all ActiveX Qt examples, and I couldn't figure out how to connect Web Browser's signals and slots manually. ( I create all widgets manually, because my experience has thought me it is actually less painful on the long run, because GUI editors tend to betray you when GUI becomes really complicated :)  ).

In Qt's QAxWidget / WebBrowser example, everything seems to be connected by some magic, and all the signals/slots work.

Although I am pretty experienced in C++ , I am pretty new to Qt, and although my other signals work (like clicked() for  QPushButton etc. ), I am not sure how to invoke this one :)  )

I would also like to note that navigating works ( webBrowser_->Navigate(...) is called in another file  ), but I can't get events to work.

I basically get bunch of those "No such signal"  warnings:

```
....

QObject::connect: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::NavigateComplete(QString) in WebAxBrowser.cpp:14
....
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::DownloadComplete()
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::DownloadComplete()
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::StatusTextChange(QString)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::StatusTextChange(QString)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::StatusTextChange(QString)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::StatusTextChange(QString)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::DownloadBegin()
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::DownloadBegin()
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::SetSecureLockIcon(int)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::SetSecureLockIcon(int)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::StatusTextChange(QString)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::StatusTextChange(QString)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::CommandStateChange(int,bool)
QObject::receivers: No such signal mis::WebAxBrowser::CommandStateChange(int,bool)
....
```

Basically, Qt gives me errors for all signals/slots related to WebBrowser :)

Here's the code :

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
/// Header File: 

namespace mis
{

class WebAxBrowser : public QAxWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:


    WebAxBrowser(QWidget* parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0);
    virtual ~WebAxBrowser();

    public slots:

    void onNavigateComplete(QString url);

    protected:

    virtual bool translateKeyEvent(int message, int keycode) const;
};

} //namespace


//// Source File:


namespace mis
{

 const QString INTERNET_EXPLORER_ACTIVE_X_UNIQUE_INDENTIFIER = "{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}";

WebAxBrowser::WebAxBrowser(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f) :  QAxWidget(parent, f)
{
    this->setControl(INTERNET_EXPLORER_ACTIVE_X_UNIQUE_INDENTIFIER);

    connect(this, 
    SIGNAL(NavigateComplete(QString)), 
    this, SLOT(onNavigateComplete(QString)));  //Am I missing something????




}


WebAxBrowser::~WebAxBrowser()
{
}

bool WebAxBrowser::translateKeyEvent(int message, int keycode) const
{
    if (message >= WM_KEYFIRST && message <= WM_KEYLAST)
    {
        return true;
    }           
    else
    {
        return QAxWidget::translateKeyEvent(message, keycode);
    }

}

void WebAxBrowser::onNavigateComplete(QString url)
{
    ///Never gets called , what am I missing? :)
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Never geets called :( ", url);
}


}
```

///end of code

I use Visual C++ 2013 Qt Addon. Qt is 5.3  32bit version on 64bit machine, Windows is 8.1, if it makes any difference :)

Thanks!

Dushan

Comment: Also, strangely enough, it works if I just don't subclass the QAxWidget class, i.e. when I call it directly :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Qt 5.6 QAxWidget documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxwidget.html#details):

Warning: You can subclass QAxWidget, but you cannot use the Q_OBJECT macro in the subclass (the generated moc-file will not compile), so you cannot add further signals, slots or properties. This limitation is due to the metaobject information generated in runtime. To work around this problem, aggregate the QAxWidget as a member of the QObject subclass.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set up signal/slot mecanism, you have to declare your signals and your slots in your header file. If you have a strong C++ background, I'm pretty sure it's not a surprise for you.

So your header file must be something like:

```
class WebAxBrowser : public QAxWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        WebAxBrowser(QWidget* parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0);
        virtual ~WebAxBrowser();

    signals:
        void NavigateComplete(QString); 

    public slots:
        void onNavigateComplete(QString url);

    protected:

    virtual bool translateKeyEvent(int message, int keycode) const;
};
```

To emit a signal, you just have to write:

```
emit(NavigateComplete(myString));
```

somewhere in your code and your slot will be called.

Comment: But how can I know when the navigation is complete?  Shouldn't that signal be emitted by a QAxWidget (ActiveX)  component? :)    Also,  why does this work when I use the QAxWidget class directly , and not when I subclass it?   Should I rephrase my question? :)    I pretty much know how signals work, I am just wondering why do some defined signals in Qt  QAxWidget don't work when you subclass QAxWidget

Comment: I don't really get your question about how can you know when your navigation is complete. Each time you emit your signal `NavigateComplete(QString)`, you launch the slot `onNavigateComplete(QString url);`. About your second question, if I find why, i'll tell you ;)